# How to get a field from the model in a forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to get the value of a form field called 'some_attribute'. I try this with `self.Meta.model.some_attribute`:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    some_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        send_mail('topic', self.Meta.model.some_attribute, 'xxx@yyyy.com', ['xxx@yyyy.com'],
              fail_silently=False)

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
```

This results in an error:
'EnrollInEventForm' object has no attribute 'some_attribute'.
How do I do that?

Comment: Did you catch the mispelling of `some_attribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I occasional strip a specific value from a form inside a view. I do that by using the `form.data` dictionary. In your case, one of the keys should be `some_attribute`. This approach might help.

Comment: yes, you are right, I had to replace `self.Meta.model.some_attribute` with `self.data['some_attribute']`

Answer (score 1):

It may be that `some_attribtue` is misspelled in Model class, t and u exchanged.

Comment: sorry, corrected it. that wasn't the issue tough, as this is only exemplary code. I have other names in my actual code.